# Get Spotlight to index a NAS

Tags: spotlight, nas

Is there a way to have Spotlight index the volumes on a NAS?

I've used this: `mdutil /Volumes/multimedia -i on`. But results aren't there next time the system starts up.

I'm running 10.11 on a Mac Pro 2012 Westmere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotlight requires use of the HFS Plus filesystem. It can't index your SMB shares. There exist some third-party solutions to iterate over your filesystem to create and maintain searchable databases, but it's not possible with Spotlight.